# Enclose a field with single quotes in a flat file

Tags: linux, sed

My file contains the below data

```
65100435|2006-04-17|27542|2868.05|1092.38|10|223.476|2006-04-20|0|1125398|3|3|2868.05
65101085|2006-04-17|2572|1306.44|411.7|10|87.34|2006-04-20|0|1250623|3|3|1306.44
```

What I need to do is to enclose the date fields with single quotes like below.

```
65100435|'2006-04-17'|27542|2868.05|1092.38|10|223.476|2006-04-20'|0|1125398|3|3|2868.05
65101085|'2006-04-17'|2572|1306.44|411.7|10|87.34|'2006-04-20'|0|1250623|3|3|1306.44
```

Can anyone help me with a sed command? thanks

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed "s/....-..-../'&'/g" file
```

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` it's pretty trivial:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{$2=q$2q;$8=q$8q}1' q="'" file
```

```
$ cat file
65100435|2006-04-17|27542|2868.05|1092.38|10|223.476|2006-04-20|0|1125398|3|3|2868.05
65101085|2006-04-17|2572|1306.44|411.7|10|87.34|2006-04-20|0|1250623|3|3|1306.44
```

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{$2=q$2q;$8=q$8q}1' q="'" file
65100435|'2006-04-17'|27542|2868.05|1092.38|10|223.476|'2006-04-20'|0|1125398|3|3|2868.05
65101085|'2006-04-17'|2572|1306.44|411.7|10|87.34|'2006-04-20'|0|1250623|3|3|1306.44
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a `sed` command, but this `awk` should do.

```
awk -F\| '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/....-..-../) $i=Q$i Q}1' OFS=\| Q="'" file
65100435|'2006-04-17'|27542|2868.05|1092.38|10|223.476|'2006-04-20'|0|1125398|3|3|2868.05
65101085|'2006-04-17'|2572|1306.44|411.7|10|87.34|'2006-04-20'|0|1250623|3|3|1306.44
```

This will enclose any field where date occurs on the line.

---

`awk` can be used with same regex as potong used:

```
awk '{gsub(/....-..-../,q"&"q)}1' q="'" file
```

Comment: Will quote fields where numbers are negative.

Comment: @jaypal fixed by using same regex as potong

Comment: We should have figured that `gsub` solution earlier. Feel like an idiot stating its trivial in `awk`. `:)`. +1 for two solutions!!

Comment: @jaypal I do agree, sometime the simple solution blows me a way, how could we miss that :)